# Are there any advantage of develop Android without ADT?

Tags: android

So, I'm new in Android development, and would like to know if is it better to program without the ADT plugin?

I'm kind lost 'cause I don't know how much difficult shall be without it, but a few minutes ago I got a stack overflow problem in eclipse cause of the plugin, just cause I deleted a simple line command...

Comment: Any advantages? No. But plenty of _disadvantages,_ yes. If you were _really_ smart, you would have asked us to solve the stack overflow issue for you :-) You still can, you know (in a different question, I would suggest).

Answer (score 2):

Developing without ADT means developing without eclipse. Because ADT plug-in is the link between Eclipse and Android SDK. you can code using command line but i will not recommend that because eclipse make it so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Find this book: (Beginning.Android.2, by Mark Murphy) In my opinion, it is a very useful book for beginners. In this book there are many basic examples which are helpful in learning to work with android.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I will look for it

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives to ADT/Java.

I know you can make it with [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). The advantage there is that it's easy for a web developer to pick up, but it doesn't allow you fine hardware control, and doesn't really look that nice, because it's basically a site made with an Android wrapper.

[Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) is really good but it's very expensive. It allows nearly as much control as ADT, supports C and OpenGL very well, so it's popular with game makers who want to publish on multiple platforms.

There are plenty of other tools that also create Android apps. ADT isn't the only way.

ADT is the 'typical' method of making Android apps, and thus the most supported. It is a little difficult to start with, but worth it if you want full low level control and optimization which the "quick" Android builder apps don't usually allow.